# How to parse array with multiple indexes only in Java Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

So lets take the following data, I'm using some JSON as below

```
[
    [
        "test",
        "bob"
    ],
    [
        "test2",
        "joe"
    ]
]
```

Here is my code snippet that I am using:

```
JSONArray parseContacts = new JSONArray(response);
ArrayList<String> aContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int x = 0; x < parseContacts.length(); x++) {
    // i tried aContacts.add(parseContacts.getString(0));
    // but of course that wont work
    // Now what??
}
```

I basically want to get the first and second string of each JSON object and of course we use a for loop to get the info, say i want to get the first and second content like this, [x][0] then [x][1], and this would give us "test", "bob", then it would move onto the second object (variable X increments) and give us "test2" and "joe". Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's pretty simple:

```
 String test = "[[\"test\",\"bob\"],[\"test2\",\"joe\"]]";
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(test);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++){
                // print: array.get(j).toString();
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```